# Setting up a wrapper to use C# .dll in C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, command-line-interface

I have a .Dll written in C#. I need to use this .Dll in a C++ application. After doing some research I am attempting to write a wrapper. I am still setting it up But I cannot get my project to compile. I have set my project up in Visual studio 2015, As a Visual C++, CLR, Class library project.

So far my code looks as follows:
C# Class:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RF182CInterface
{
    public class RFIDInterface
    {
        public RFIDInterface()
        {
        .
        .
        .
```

.H file

```
// RFIDWrapper.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace RFIDWrapper {

    class RFIDWrapperIFacePrivate;

    class __declspec(dllexport) RFIDWrapperIFace
    {
    private:
        RFIDWrapperIFacePrivate* _private;

    public:
        RFIDWrapperIFace();
        ~RFIDWrapperIFace();
    };
}
```

.cpp file:

```
// This is the main DLL file.
#using "RF182CInterface.dll";

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
#include "RFIDWrapper.h"

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; // Marshal

class RFIDWrapperIFacePrivate
{
public:
    msclr::auto_gcroot<RF182CInterface::RFIDInterface^> rf182CInterface;
};
```

When I attempt to compile I get the following errors:

Warning 1   warning C4627: '#using "RF182CInterface.dll"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
Error   2   error C2653: 'RF182CInterface' : is not a class or namespace name
Error   3   error C2065: 'RFIDInterface' : undeclared identifier
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : '>' 
Error   5   error C2976: 'msclr::auto_gcroot' : too few template arguments

I believe they all stem from the warning where the .dll is skipped. The .dll is in the same folder as the .cpp and .h files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n

Comment: Just turn off precompiled headers in the project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include "stdafx.h"` has to be the *first line* in your object file, any `#using` come after it (or better, inside it).